# Can the dynamic library not ending with dylib？

Tags: ios, cocoa, dynamic-library

I found in some framework bundle, the **dynamic library** not ending with **dylib**. I am wondering if **dylib** is required suffix for any dynamic library under IOS/Cocoa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dylib` is a file extension and as any file extension it is just a hint for what *should* be the format of a file.

Changing the extension doesn't change the content or the format and is therefore allowed.